# Change VSCode extension setting before executing unit test

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue when trying to test a modification to an extension I made. I added a configuration option which I want to change to a certain value before the test executes.

I've found that you can get the configuration with:

```
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('module').get('setting')
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('module').update('setting', x, true)
```

However it complains that

```
No editors associated with document: /home/username/.config/Code/User/settings.json
```

And exits with a timeout.

Is there any easier way to temporarily set VSCode user settings, just for a single test? Because I wouldn't want to mess with the user settings.